# Lower bound on the off-diagonal elements of a PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices, matrix-norms

Suppose we have a PSD matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}$, which could be written in the following block form
$$X=[X_1\quad X_2;\quad X_2^\top\quad X_3],$$
where $X_1, X_3\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are PSD matrices, and $X_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

**My question is**: could we find a lower bound of the $(i, i)$-th element of the off-diagonal sub-matrix $X_2$, based on $\Vert X\Vert_2$, or $\Vert X_1\Vert_2$, or trace($X$), or trace($X_1$).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Among the values you listed, the only one that could potentially yield a lower bound is $\|X\|_2$.

Comment: Could u provide more details about this bound? Thanks!

Comment: For one, you have
$$
\|X\| \leq \|X_1\|_2 + 2\|X_2\|_2 + \|X_3\|_2 \implies \|X_2\|_2 \geq \frac 12 (\|X_1\|_2 - \|X_1\|_2-\|X_3\|_2) 
$$

Comment: But $X_2$ is not necessarily PSD, the lower bound of $\Vert X_2\Vert_2$ does not yield a lower bound of the $(,)$-th entry of $X_2$.